# Handling Database Cross Foreign Keys

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have the following tables:

USER table:

```
id | username | password | join_date | avatar_image_id
```

IMAGE table:

```
id | url | user_owner_id
```

image table holds all images of posts, articles and user avatars. each image belongs to a user who can edit it. so `user_owner_id` is necessary but it is not enough to know which image is the user's avatar so I need `avatar_image_id`.

Does this cross foreign key make problem? is it a bad design? and is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

**Option 1**

You do this in the IMAGE table:-

```
id
url
user_owner_id
user_avatar_id
```

- `user_avatar_id` column is a foreign key to the USER table
- `user_avatar_id` allows NULLs, indicating the image is not an avatar for anyone
- Since each user has only one Avatar, `user_avatar_id` should be made unique

This has the advantage that you can continue to treat all images generically in code that only needs the first three columns.  Only when you have specific code that is used for Avatar images will you need to consider the last column.

This effectively enforces a rule that "each user has 0 or 1 avatars".  Perhaps when a user is first created, they don't have an avatar yet so this is ok?  If every user strictly must have an avatar and you want to enforce this in the database you need Option 2.

**Option 2**

How necessary is it that all images go in the same table?  Do you often treat avatar images and other images generically with the same piece of code?  If not, you could consider adding the following column to the USER table:-

```
avatar_url
```

This would make it quick and easy to find the avatar image for a given user.  However, it may complicate image editing code because now you have to consider things stored in the `image` table as well as these special avatar images.

On balance, I would probably choose Option 1.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes `Cross Foreign Keys` are a painful, specially in case you want to delete (or archive). This because you'll not be able delete neither of the rows.

A way to handle this is just defining the `FOREIGN KEY` with `NOCHECK` constraint to the `avatar_image_id`

Another way is adding a `BIT` column to table  `IMAGE` `IsAvatarImage`. With the right indexes, the performance impact for this approach should be minimal.

Comment: how about changing `user_owner_id` from foreign key to a normal row? i dont need to search on it so much. usual joins are from user table to image and not vice versa.

Comment: @sheno . your question was about `design` :-) . `user_owner_id` is the stronger `FOREIGN KEY`. Searching is different thing in the conceptual database design.

Comment: just to clarify, when I wrote stronger, I meant that `user_owner_id` can't be replaced in anyway, while `avatar_image_id` can be replaced as I wrote with the `IMAGE.IsAvatarImage` `BIT`